# Google App Engine MemcacheException

Tags: google-app-engine

google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache put: Set failed to set 1 keys: [B@1c09b65
facing this exception without using any memcache sevice in application.Has anybody faced this before? whats the reason?

Comment: What kind of data do you put in cache? Is it Serializable?

Comment: Have a look at his: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/bb363b18aaa7d68b/c0af5ceca66621c2

Answer (score 0):

I cant recall seeing this before, but regarding your mention of not using the memcache service, I know that if you using ndb as imported below in python, App Engine automatically includes and utilizes memcache without any needed input/interaction/configuration on your part.

from google.appengine.ext import ndb